# JPA @OneToOne leeds to SQLSyntaxErrorException

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

First entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SCOL_INSCRIPTION_ETUDIANT")
public class ScolInscriptionEtudiant implements Serializable {

    @EmbeddedId
    ScolInscriptionEtudiantId id;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "FSPN_KEY")
    private ScolFormationSpecialisation scolFormationSpecialisation;

    @Column(name = "FSPN_KEY")
    private Long fspnkey;
```

Second entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SCOLARITE.SCOL_FORMATION_SPECIALISATION")
public class ScolFormationSpecialisation {

 @Id
 @Column(name = "FSPN_KEY")
 private Long fspnkey;

 @OneToOne(mappedBy = "scolFormationSpecialisation")
 private ScolInscriptionEtudiant scolInscriptionEtudiant;
```

Those 2 tables share the same column 'fspnkey', that I want to use to join the data.

Repository:

```
public interface StudentDetailRepository extends CrudRepository<ScolInscriptionEtudiant, Long> {
    List<ScolInscriptionEtudiant> findAllByEtudnumero(String etudnumero);
```

Calling the repository generate this error:

```
Caused by: oracle.jdbc.OracleDatabaseException: ORA-00904: "SCOLINSCRI0_"."SCOL_FORMATION_SPECIALISATION_FSPN_KEY" : invalid identifier
```

I follow this guide: https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-one-to-one

Do you see what is wrong in this code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need fspnkey in first entity. And change you @JoinColumn to

```
@JoinColumn(name = "scolFormationSpecialisation_id", referencedColumnName = "FSPN_KEY")
```

Comment: still not working, with this message: "Caused by: oracle.jdbc.OracleDatabaseException: ORA-00904: "SCOLINSCRI0_"."SCOL_FORMATION_SPECIALISATION_ID" : identificateur non valide"

Comment: Are you using the right hibernate dialect for Oracle?

Comment: Also SCOL_FORMATION_SPECIALISATION_ID is 32 char wide. This is invalid for oracle. You have to keep it below 30. Like sfs_id or something. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

In your @JoinColumn values you need to provide the "name" property as well , this actually points the unique column in ScolFormationSpecialisation.
See the example in the link . It has the name="address_id" in User Table points to "id" in address table.

Comment: I have try with and without 'name'. As I understand, name is optional.